# Is it possible to gzip file on server-side and ungzip it in the browser transparently?

Tags: javascript, http, gzip, content-encoding

My web application sends JSON files to client. These files can be relatively big.

Can I compress them on server-side and receive uncompressed on client side transparently?

For example, if I write

```
$.getJSON( "ajax/test.json", function( data ) {
...
});
```

can I just have `ajax/test.json` gzipped and set content-encoding to gzip?

Comment: Yes. Typically, this is a configuration item for your webserver, you don't have to do anything programmatically or change your files.

Comment: So, if I just have stati JSON laying on server (say, AWS) it is compressed most probably?

Comment: Maybe, depends how you set up your server. It's trivial to check by looking at the network tab in the browser's dev tools.

Answer (score 2):

You have not specified any information about your server-side setup.

If you are generating the json on the fly, then you should check if the request send by the browser contains `Accept-Encoding: gzip` header.
If yes, then add header `Content-Encoding: gzip` to the response and just sent gzip compressed data.

If the json files are static you should configure `application/json` mime type as compressible in your webserver configuration, or better yet, precompress it,  store both file.json and file.json.gz on your webserver and then configure conditional rewrite and headers, so the compressed file is served only to clients that supports compression.
 Search/Ask ServerFault how to do this on your webserver.